# Fetch value from DB using Macros

Tags: mysql, macros

I need to do the below update through macros in MYSQL,

```
If tbname = "PARTY" Then                
Dim ssql As String              
ssql = SELECT MAX(PARTY_ID) FROM PARTY              
DB.Execute ssql, 64        
End If
```

I need to use above output i.e., Max(party_id) to update the party table.
That is,

```
UPDATE PARTY PARTY_ID = (output of SELECT MAX(PARTY_ID) FROM PARTY)
WHERE PARTY_ID='DUMMY'
```

Kindly advise how can we implement this using resultset concept

Answer (score 0):

I also need answer for this..
Need to know how we can use result set concept to update a table based on the value of other ta